# Cannot convert 'ViewController.Type' to 'UIViewController in Facebook shareDialog

Tags: swift

I think this is outdated on Facebook swift documentation and it is giving errors. I fixed the first line error but it is giving error in `viewcontroller` line

I am facing this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Type' to expected
>   argument type 'UIViewController'

Please somebody give a fix.

```
import FacebookShare

    let content = LinkShareContent(url: 
    NSURL("https://developers.facebook.com")) //Fixed :- let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com")!)


try ShareDialog.show(from: myViewController, content: content)  //Error :- Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have passed the **class** instead of an **instance** of the class. You need to pass the instance of your `myViewController` (which should be a subclass of `UIViewController` of course)

```
try ShareDialog.show(from: myViewController(), content: content)
```

---

**Note:** You should use UpperCamelCase for class names - `MyViewController`. Currently, it looks like it is an instance variable. From [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming),

> **Follow case conventions.** Names of types and protocols are
>   UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.